# yarn dev failed in WSL (error: not an absolute path)

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I install nvm and yarn in WSL, and my web project folder is on Windows F:/ , when I run `yarn dev` in WSL bash, vite come out an error:

```sh
➜  testProject yarn dev
yarn run v1.22.11
warning package.json: No license field
$ vite
 > error: The working directory "/mnt/f/testProject" is not an absolute path

error when starting dev server:
Error: Build failed with 1 error:
error: The working directory "/mnt/f/testProject"
is not an absolute path
    at failureErrorWithLog (/mnt/f/testProject/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1449:15)
    at /mnt/f/testProject/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1131:28
    at runOnEndCallbacks (/mnt/f/testProject/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:921:63)
    at buildResponseToResult (/mnt/f/testProject/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1129:7)
    at /mnt/f/testProject/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1236:14
    at /mnt/f/testProject/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:609:9
    at handleIncomingPacket (/mnt/f/testProject/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:706:9)
    at Socket.readFromStdout (/mnt/f/testProject/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:576:7)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at Socket.emit (domain.js:470:12)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

WSL Path:

```sh
➜  testProject where yarn
/home/gowsl/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.5/bin/yarn
/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/yarn

➜  testProject where npm
/home/gowsl/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.5/bin/npm
/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm

➜  testProject which npm
/home/gowsl/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.5/bin/npm

➜  testProject which yarn
/home/gowsl/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.5/bin/yarn
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are **using yarn installed in Windows**, that's so many packages that may not work with the WSL environment.

See [Vite does not work on Windows WSL#4802](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/4802#issuecomment-909303005). Maybe that can help you.

(Even if this issue has been solved, posted an answer here for a record.)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).